# efficiently serve images from app engine with readable URL

Tags: image, google-app-engine, amazon-s3

Whats a fast and or cheap way to serve an image from a readable url on google app engine:

```
<img src="http//mycustomdomain.com/image-server/my-readable-url>
```

(these urls cant be changed so I can't use get_serving_url without the cost of a redirect)

In the documentation on [Serving a Blob](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Serving_a_blob):

> Note: If you are serving images, a more efficient and potentially
>   less-expensive method is to use get_serving_url using the App Engine
>   Images API rather than send_blob. The get_serving_url function lets
>   you serve the image directly, without having to go through your App
>   Engine instances.

Here are five options off the top of my head that i'm considering based on the size of the image & how quickly the image needs to be returned. (each option would hopefully use edge cache)

1. Datastore lookup for serving url (precomputed by get_serving_url) & redirect to serving url.
2. Datastore lookup for blobkey & send_blob
3. Datastore lookup for blobProperty & send out (increased storage cost but maybe ok for icons etc)
4. Somehow bake the URL into a google cloud storage [bucket name](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming) to avoid datastore lookup and simply redirect to that bucket (assuming this isn't possible?)
5. Some appy.yaml hack that queues up these images and deploys them to app engine as static files falling back to options 1-4 if static file not found. (assuming option 5 isn't possible?)

(datastore costs $0.18 / GB / Month, static files and blobstore cost only $0.026 / GB / Month)

Are there any other options I haven't considered? Is option 2 the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using google cloud storage with a custom domain.

see here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

you can upload to cloud storage from your app:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/
(that's for java)

Comment: I may still need to serve some traffic from app engine - Will see how things go.